# How can I find the fundamental component classes in the manifest.xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android and Java ,I am trying to find online examples for codes and read them to understand the structure of the codes. I have been through this file manifest.xml of my first app:

```
<original-package android:name="com.android.alarmclock" />
<original-package android:name="com.android.deskclock" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"></uses-sdk>

<application android:label="@string/app_label"
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock">

    <provider android:name="AlarmProvider"
            android:authorities="com.android.deskclock"
            android:exported="false" />

    <activity android:name="DeskClock"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:theme="@style/DeskClock"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias android:name="DockClock"
            android:targetActivity="DeskClock"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:theme="@style/DeskClock"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:enabled="@bool/config_dockAppEnabled"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DESK_DOCK" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    <activity android:name="AlarmClock"
            android:label="@string/alarm_list_title"
            android:theme="@style/AlarmClockTheme"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:exported="true" />

    <activity-alias android:name="com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock"
            android:targetActivity="com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"
            android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name="SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".worldclock.CitiesActivity"
            android:label="@string/cities_activity_title"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="SetAlarm"
            android:label="@string/set_alarm"
            android:theme="@style/SetAlarmTheme"/>

    <activity android:name="AlarmAlert"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/>

    <!-- This activity is basically the same as AlarmAlert
         but full-screen so that it can turn the display on. -->
    <activity android:name="AlarmAlertFullScreen"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/AlarmAlertFullScreenTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/>

    <activity android:name="ScreensaverActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/ScreensaverActivityTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard" />

    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
            <action android:name="alarm_killed" />
            <action android:name="cancel_snooze" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name="HandleSetAlarm"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:permission="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- This service receives the same intent as AlarmReceiver but it does
         not respond to the same broadcast. The AlarmReceiver will receive
         the alert broadcast and will start this service with the same
         intent. The service plays the alarm alert and vibrates the device.
         This allows the alert to continue playing even if another activity
         causes the AlarmAlert activity to pause. -->
    <service android:name="AlarmKlaxon"
            android:exported="false"
            android:description="@string/alarm_klaxon_service_desc">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="AlarmInitReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.alarmclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/analog_gadget"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.oldName" android:value="com.android.deskclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/analog_appwidget" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.alarmclock.DigitalAppWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/digital_gadget"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/digital_appwidget" />
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.android.alarmclock.DigitalAppWidgetService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
         android:exported="false" />

    <receiver android:name="com.android.alarmclock.DigitalWidgetViewsFactory"
         android:exported="false" />

    <!-- Dream (screensaver) implementation -->
    <service android:name="Screensaver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_label">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.dream"
            android:resource="@xml/dream_info" />
    </service>

    <!-- Settings activity for screensaver -->
    <activity android:name=".ScreensaverSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/screensaver_settings"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- This activity is basically like the TimerFragment in DeskClock
     but only during lock screen
     so that is only has the fired timers -->
    <activity android:name="com.android.deskclock.timer.TimerAlertFullScreen"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/AlarmAlertFullScreenTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/>

    <service android:name="TimerRingService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:description="@string/timer_ring_service_desc">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.TIMER_ALERT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.deskclock.timer.TimerReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="start_timer" />
            <action android:name="delete_timer" />
            <action android:name="times_up" />
            <action android:name="timer_stop" />
            <action android:name="timer_reset" />
            <action android:name="timer_done" />
            <action android:name="timer_update" />
            <action android:name="notif_in_use_show" />
            <action android:name="notif_in_use_cancel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.android.deskclock.stopwatch.StopwatchService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:description="@string/stopwatch_service_desc">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="start_stopwatch" />
            <action android:name="lap_stopwatch" />
            <action android:name="stop_stopwatch" />
            <action android:name="reset_stopwatch" />
            <action android:name="share_stopwatch" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

I have question (hope to be patient I am really new on all of this) :

Which tag does represent the classes in the app? and Is there fundamental classes? because one of the questions about this code was "identify one instance of each fundamental component considering there are four fundemental component classes in the mainfest.xml"

Comment: @Basel--You might find [this manifest structure overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) valuable. I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which tag does represent the classes in the app?

Your app will, more than likely, will have classes that are not defined on the `AndroidManifest.xml`

> and Is there fundamental classes?

By fundamental classes I believe they are referring to `ContentProvider`, `BroadcastRecevier`, `Activity`, and `Service`. These classes are considered to be the building blocks of most apps. These are the classes that will be defined on the `AndroidManifest.xml`, although some of them are not required to be defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and can be registered via code.

You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#Components).

Answer (score 3):

There are four types of components in an android applicaiton

- Activity
- Services
- BroadcastReceiver
- ContentProvider

  ```
        <activity android:name="AlarmAlertFullScreen"
                          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                          android:theme="@style/AlarmAlertFullScreenTheme"
                          android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                          android:taskAffinity=""
                          android:showOnLockScreen="true"
                          android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
                          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/>

  all <activity> Tag keep defined Activity classes in your app

           <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"
                      android:exported="false">
                  <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
                      <action android:name="alarm_killed" />
                      <action android:name="cancel_snooze" />
                  </intent-filter>
           </receiver>

       <receiver> Tag define BroadCastReceiver component which is used in applicaiton



          <service android:name="AlarmKlaxon"
                  android:exported="false"
                  android:description="@string/alarm_klaxon_service_desc">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
              </intent-filter>
          </service>
  ```

  tag define background service component of your applicaiton

  ```
          <provider android:name="AlarmProvider"
                  android:authorities="com.android.deskclock"
                  android:exported="false" />

  <provider> tag define shared resource like database which is Content Provider
  ```

for more details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html